# React server and client rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Using https://github.com/ayoubdev/reactjs-isomorphic-starterkit as a boiletplate.

I'm trying to figure out how to inject the client's bundle into the server rendering process.

As the webpack build for server and client is well separated, is there a simple trick to achieve this goal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about the specifics of this boilerplate repo. But I can try to explain the main idea, and you can dig deeper.

The basic idea is, use a bundler (in this case, webpack is used, gulp, grunt, whatever else is fine as long as you transpile) and build a bundle based on the entry point for your React components. Then link this bundle via script tag in some html file.

For the server side, you can use [ReactDOMServer.renderToString](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver). Import your component(s), pass them into ReactDOM.renderToString. Pass the HTML to some templater like ejs or use a raw HTML string and call React.render from the server.

### Client side.

In your example, the entry point is [here](https://github.com/ayoubdev/reactjs-isomorphic-starterkit/blob/master/src/client/index.jsx) and hooked [here](https://github.com/ayoubdev/reactjs-isomorphic-starterkit/blob/master/src/client/index.html). Notice the `<div class= "app">` tag. This is tag we are referencing in our entry point. We also reference our bundled js from webpack via script tag, `client.bundle.js`.

### Server side

In your example, the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/ayoubdev/reactjs-isomorphic-starterkit/blob/8ca550139a55285e7648d77f6313362ffe7e884d/src/server/index.jsx). Notice the `renderComponent` function. It builds a string based on the HTML of the component supplied from `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`, which is called on `Line 39`. It then sends all of that html back as a response in `res.send`

This [blog article](https://www.terlici.com/2015/03/18/fast-react-loading-server-rendering.html) uses jade as an example, which you can use as an alternative if you find this boilerplate a bit much.

Comment: thanks fzxt, but my question is more how to inject the client bundle with ReactDOMServer.renderToString. Which does means that I have to build both the client and server, is there a simple magic trick to merge them both ?

Comment: A potential idea is to build a html doc string with a script tag that contains your client bundle code, and the html from the reactDOMServer.renderToString  and then send them back as a response from the server.

Comment: i'll try using concurrently to have the script tag from a other port dedicated to the client side. Thanks fzxt